# Running JavaFX 2.1 on mac with jdk 1.6 error Unable to read

Tags: macos, javafx, javafx-2

I am using latest Mac OSX and installed java1.6 and trying latest JAvaFX 2.1 developer version of JavaFX

Once i configure java and javafx and when i try to run the sample javafx program i am getting following error

in command prompt i am getting following error

```
$java -jar Ensemble.jar 

Unable to read ../rt/lib/jfxrt.jar
Unable to read ../../../../rt/lib/jfxrt.jar
Unable to read ../../sdk/rt/lib/jfxrt.jar
Unable to read ../../../artifacts/sdk/rt/lib/jfxrt.jar
```

In the windows i am getting

```
Unable to run JavaFX Runtime
```

Comment: Same issue here on Linux

Answer (score 0):

There is no runtime for Mac yet, so you need to place folder with Ensemble inside folder with JavaFX SDK.

```
sdk -> samples -> Ensemble.jar
    -> rt -> lib -> jfxrt.jar
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If the current dir is: `<project dir>/target`

then the following works on Linux:

In parent dir of `<project dir>`:

```
ln -s $JAVAFX_HOME sdk
```

where $JAVAFX_HOME points to your JavaFX installation directory.

If the current dir is: `<project dir>` (e.g. when running from NetBeans)

then the following works on Linux:

In parent dir of `<project dir>`:

```
ln -s $JAVAFX_HOME/rt rt
```

Maybe something similar works on Mac as well?

Note: I don't know if this is the recommended way or if there is a better way, though.

Answer (score -1):

I've encountered this problem before, This is my solution:

1. set environment variable called JAVAFX_SDK, easy to remember and typing less.

   ```
   export JAVAFX_SDK=/path/to/javafx-sdk
   ```
2. Run application like below instruction

   ```
   java -Djavafx.runtime.path=$JAVAFX_SDK/rt -jar Ensemble.jar
   ```